# C++ do OS X or Linux headers vary

Tags: c++, linux, macos, header, porting

I am making a program that I want to run on both Lubuntu (linux) and Tiger (mac os x). I am including some header functions like "termios", "sys/select" and "unistd" that I have never heard of before. Which leads me to the question: Are there any built-in libraries in Linux that are not included in OS X, or vice versa? Can someone explain which ones they are? I think this would be a good thing for me to know if/when porting programs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be sure anything in POSIX is definitely in both OSes. This includes [`<termios>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/termios.h.html), [`<unistd.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html), and [`<sys/select.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/select.h.html). POSIX is a superset of C99.

Apart from that, anything goes. Most common libraries used on Linux also work on BSD-type systems like Mac OS X, but they cannot be assumed to be "built-in".

The OpenGroup provides [an exhaustive list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/functions.html) of all the POSIX system interfaces.

Since the question is tagged `C++`, you obviously also have access to the C++ Standard library, of which a decent (but not perfect) reference is available [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).